# Git / Heroku: SDK location not found

Tags: android, git, heroku, travis-ci

I have a project stored in **Github** and linked to **Travis** for CI. This combination works. Now I'm trying to deploy this code to **Heroku**. However, my pushes to Heroku (with `git push heroku master`) are returning me this error:

```
 remote:        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    remote:
    remote:        * What went wrong:
    remote:        A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    remote:        > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
    remote:
    remote:        * Try:
    remote:        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    remote:
    remote:        BUILD FAILED
    remote:
    remote:        Total time: 40.505 secs
    remote:
    remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to run Gradle!
    remote:        We're sorry this build is failing. If you can't find the issue in application
    remote:        code, please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com
    remote:        You can also try reverting to the previous version of the buildpack by running:
    remote:        $ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-gradle#previous-version
    remote:
    remote:        Thanks,
    remote:        Heroku
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Gradle app.
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:
    remote: !       Push rejected to (projectName).
    remote:
    To https://git.heroku.com/(projectName).git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/(projectName).git'
```

It says I need to discriminate the SDK location in a *location.properties* file.

Well, how could I? Doesn't Travis automatically installs SDK on every build? How could I point to something dinamically created?

What am I missing?

Comment: have managed to resolve that ? Have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you just running `git push heroku master` at the end of your `.travis.yml` file after the tests? Or are you running it in a separate `deploy:` step?

Have you tried using the Travis CI [Heroku deployment addon](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku/) instead of deploying via `git push` ? Maybe that will work.